# Reset GID/UID auto-increment numbers

Tags: linux, centos, user-management, groups

I created a virtual mail user for postfix virtual mailboxes with a gid/uid of 5555, but now every new user I create starts at > 5555, is it possible to reset the autonumbering so normal users will be back in the low 100s? I know this appears pedantic, but I am OCD AND 5555 is supposed to signify a "special" user, much like 65534 does for anonymous NFS user.

**--Update--**

Confirming that ssgelm's solution works. I changed `/etc/login.defs` and set the UID_MAX and GID_MAX to 5000, and all new users are now getting uids/gids in the low 500s (expected behavior).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the man page (http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd):

```
UID_MAX (number), UID_MIN (number)
    Range of user IDs used for the creation of regular users by useradd or newusers.
```

I'm pretty sure that if you set UID_MAX in `/etc/login.defs` to 5554 you will get the behavior you are looking for.